# How to prove that this function is surjective given domain and co-domain?

Tags: functions

I really need help with this question on functions, would really appreciate it!

Let us denote by $|s|$ the length of a sequence $s$ and $[m..n]$ for the set of natural numbers between $m$ and $n$.

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$ let $B_k$ be the set of sequences of bits of length
$\leq k$. Note that this will always contain the empty sequence
because its length is $0$.
For arbitrary $m,n\geq1$ define a function
$h:B_m\times B_n\rightarrow [0..m+n]$ by $h(s,t)=|s|+|t|$.
Prove that $h$ is surjective.

So what I'm thinking so far is that as long as $m+n > 2$, we can show that the co-domain contains an element $3$, but the maximum value of $|s|+|t|$ is $1 + 1 = 2$, thus the element in 3 is not mapped from the domain. I'm not sure if this is valid. But I'm having problems figuring out why it's surjective when $m+n = 1$, because then $[0..m+n] = {0, 1, 2}$ and everything seems included.

Would really really really appreciate your help!

Comment: Are $B_k$ sets of **all** sequences of length $\leq k$?

Comment: Yeah I think so

Answer (score 1):

To show that $h$ is surjective, we need to show that every integer $x\in [0,m+n]$ in the domain can be written as $h(s,t)$ for some $s,t$.

Let $a=\min\{m,x\}$, and set $b=x-a$. Observe that $a\in [0,m]$. Moreover, $b\in [0,n]$, since when $a=m$ we see that $b=x-m\leq (m+n)-m=n$, and when $a=x$ we have $b=0$.

Now let $s$ be any string of length $a$, and let $t$ be any string of length $b$. As we have shown $a\leq m$ and $b\leq n$, it follows that $s\in B_m$ and $t\in B_n$. Now since $h(s,t)=a+b=x$, it follows that $h$ is surjective.